# Using Azure Durable Function for Aggregation

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am super stuck... I need an Azure function that is able to receive some number of packets of data and then do something with that data once it is all received. The function is being called with an HTTP request and initially the request contains some parameters, among which is the quantity of data packets to be received. I have a client function that receives data and and starts the orchestrator... but no matter what I seem to do, my orchestrator fails with a TypeError: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable error before any data is even sent over. The data to be sent over is a series of integers and the desired output is a count of integers received (so nothing complicated)

The expectation is that the first time the function is called it will return the instance id, then the function will be called an additional n times to receive each integer and once this is completed it will output the count.

Can someone point me in the right direction how I can make this work? I am probably missing a piece in this process but I can't seem to figure out why the orchestrator is failing. This is my orchestrator function:

```
async def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):

input_data = context.get_input()
n_count = int(input_data['n_count'])
# there are some other parameters, but they are not relevant

my_data = []

for i in range(n_count):
    result = await context.wait_for_external_event("get_data")
    my_data.append(result)

total_received = len(df)

return total_received
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to re-create the issue without the http function and some sample data which the trigger function receives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually able to figure this out, so to anyone else looking to aggregate data using a durable function, here is a simplified example. In this example the function is called by a Power Automate flow using HTTP POST. The anticipated number of data packets is passed as a query (n_count). The response to the initial function call yields the sendEventPostUri and data is then sent to this Uri via HTTP POST. Once all the data has been received the function returns the total (via HTTP GET).

The client is as follows:

```
async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> func.HttpResponse:
    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    n_count = int(req.params.get('n_count')) 
    instance_id = await client.start_new('my_aggregator', None, {'n_count': n_count })

    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
```

The orchestrator is as follows:

```
 def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    try: 
        input_data = context.get_input()
        n_count = int(input_data['n_count'])
        my_data = []

        for i in range(n_count):
            result = yield context.wait_for_external_event("get_data")
            my_data.append(result)
           
        total = sum(my_data)

        return total

    except Exception as e:
        context.set_custom_status("Failed")
        raise
```